# Strange Transparency Issue in IE8 - Green phone icons?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, png

I'll preface this saying I've spent quite a bit (actually, an absurd) amount of time trying to troubleshoot this issue.

So, the site/specific page I'm having trouble with is at http://staging.htsdlaw.com/about-us. I believe this issue occurs on most of the pages.

Of course, like many IE8 bugs, I have trouble repeating the issue; but apparently it's happening on several Client machines running IE8. Here are his full specs:

```
Windows 7
Internet Explorer 8
User Agent: 
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0;
Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2;
.NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media
Center PC 6.0; MDDR; .NET CLR
1.1.4322; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C)
```

This happens when he clicks on "About Us" and lands on the page, or when he refreshes on that page. When he loads the page, he sees these strange green phone icons. They go away when he moves his mouse into the content area.

You can view a screenshot here:
http://cloud.believelabs.com/image/3c1S2Z2H0i2S/green_ie8_bug.png

As for script libraries, I'm using jQuery 1.7++, Superfish.js, jQuery Cycle, and jQuery easing.

I haven't been able to recreate this, period, at any point in my development process. I'm simply running a Windows 7 virtual machine on my OSX machine and swapping the Developer Tools setting.

When and if you're checking it out, keep in mind that I'm using an HTML class to set the tiles to JPG formats for IE only. For example, html.ie `#main { background-image: same_file.jpg }`.

As always, thank you all so much for your help. I try my best to research and resolve as many issues as I can (often as a result of this site).

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to give a certain answer without being able to replicate the problem, but when you have problems in IE with some copies of IE but not others that are seemingly identical, there are usually one of two issues involved:

1. Compatibility mode. If one of the copies of IE is viewing the site in compatibility mode and the other isn't, then you'll obviously see differences between the two. As for why they would be doing this, it's not always clear, but tends to be the user's browser config. Sometimes it can also be triggered unexpectedly if you browse a site inside your local intranet.
2. Missing ActiveX controls. My hunch is that this is the problem here, because it often happens with opacity and stuff like that. The browser won't report any errors, but effects simply won't be rendered. This is caused by either the browser blocking the ActiveX controls due to its security settings, or the activeX control simply not being installed properly. Since these controls are typically standard Windows controls, it's a mystery why they are sometimes missing, but it does seem to happen fairly often.

Because both of these issues occur in user-land, it's pretty much impossible to predict or mitigate against them, other than have the site cope gracefully if it can't do something.